# Can I get the specific field(s) that caused a duplicate exception in MySQL?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, exception

I am using ASP.NET C# to insert records into a MySql database.  I have a method that looks similar to this:

```
public bool InsertRecord()
{
    string message;
    try
    {
        //Insert and Save
        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {

         if(ex.InnerException != null)
         {
             message = ex.InnerException is MySqlException
             ? MySqlErrors.GetMySqlErrorMessage(((MySqlException)ex.InnerException).Number)
             : ex.InnerException.Message;
         }
         else
         {
              message = ex.Message;
         }

         return false;
     }
 }
```

Currently, if it gets into the catch, the `Message` property of the `Exception` is:

`"Duplicate entry 'xxxxx-bbbbb' for key 'index_1"`

This is cryptic to the user, so I was curious if there was a way to get specific information on what field(s) caused the duplicate exception, for example, `"Field B already exists in the in table".` or `"Field A and B" already exist in the table".`

If it is easy to get the specific fields, I thought of two other options and would like opinions on them.  They are:

1. I know which field(s) cause duplicate errors, so I thought one way I could be more specific was to check if the record with the field(s) already exists in the database and if it does, report that to the user. This way, I avoid the exception, but it would require an extra database call.
2. The other way I thought was to have another class for specific exceptions that I can store the fields that are key or unique fields, so for example, if a user tries to update a car table and the VIN is unique, I could simply catch the exception, but since I know what table they are trying to update, I could say:  `"A record with VIN "abc" already exists".`

Comment: How is your table estructure and how is your insert query.

Comment: @RobertRozas, some tables have a primary key, but most have unique indexes composed of multiple columns.  My insert statement is just using LINQ to Insert a record, basically I add the changed record to the context and call SaveChanges() on the context.

Comment: Is your program supposed to be inserting a duplicate record, or updating the original record? Or is a person really entering in a bunch of data that coincidentally duplicates a primary key? I'd say fix your logic so the exception doesn't happen in the first place (option 1)... and then update the record (if that is what should happen) instead of erroring.

Comment: The program should not even allow duplicates, it can't, it will violate the database constraints.  Currently, I'm just catching it, but I am leaning towards option 1 too.

Answer (score 0):

In the message

> "Duplicate entry 'xxxxx-bbbbb' for key 'index_1'"

- `index_1` is the name of the constraint that was about to be violated
- `xxxxx-bbbbb` are the duplicate values that would have been inserted.

By parsing the table definition (eg. `SHOW CREATE TABLE the_table`), you can deduce which fields were involved.

[edit]

It is probably easier to retrieve the columns involved by querying the `information_schema` database:

```
SELECT column_name
FROM information_schema.key_column_usage
WHERE constraint_schema = DATABASE()
AND table_name = '<your table name>'
AND constraint_name = '<constraint name>';
```

Comment: I will provide working code on request. Friday evening laziness, sorry.

Comment: In your bullet points, are you saying that is what I should tell the user, because that is still cryptic to them. This would still require an extra database call, so probably best to check for a duplicate before trying to save.

Comment: What I meant is that you can extract the (hopefully meaningful) column names from the constraint mentionned in the error message. It does indeed require querying the database for information about this constraint.

Comment: Yes, but what is the point if I try to save and cause an exception and then call the database again, parse the error message when I can just check for a duplicate before hand. And the name of the index will not always be index_1. This is doable, but it just seems like more work.

Comment: I certainly do not dispute the fact that it is far-fetched a solution ;) But this seems to be the only way I can think of to answer your question. Oh and the workflow I had in mind was: 1. try to insert a record, 2. if you get a "Duplicate entry" error, extract the index name from the error message 3. query `information_schema` to get the column names. Or perhaps we all agree and I missed a point of your last comment :)